# Elixir Ecto custom primary keys

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to rename the primary key from `:id` to `:account_id`.

I've got the following `Schema` and migration. When I try to insert a record, I get a 'cannot be null' error from Postgres on the account_id column.

Did I set up the autogenerate bit right? I feel like that should be in the migration.

```
  def change do
    create table(:accounts) do
      add :account_id, :integer, primary_key: true
      add :email, :string
      timestamps()
    end
  end


  @primary_key {:account_id, :id, autogenerate: true}
  schema "accounts" do
    field :email, :string
    timestamps()
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `primary_key: false` option:

```
  def change do
    create table(:accounts, primary_key: false) do
      add :account_id, :integer, primary_key: true
      add :email, :string
      timestamps()
    end
  end
```

[Edit]

As the questioner himself wrote in his answer, we can use `:bigserial` instead of `:integer` here.

The `:bigserial` takes 8 bytes and the `:integer` takes 4 bytes.

From Ecto 2.0 (released 2016) the default type of primary keys is `:bigserial`,
but we can safely use `:integer` for ordinary purpose as it is still very big (1 to 2,147,483,647).

Comment: Should :account_id be of type :integer, or type :id?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't obvious from the docs or other guides. The trick is to the `:bigserial` type for the `:id` field.

```
  def change do
    create table(:accounts, primary_key: false) do
      add :account_id, :bigserial, primary_key: true
      add :email, :string
      timestamps()
    end
  end
```